Rasgos sintácticos de la escritura matemática
El fenómeno al que me refiero no es (según entiendo) particular al idioma español sino que lo he visto también reflejado en textos matemáticos ingleses o portugueses (y, según he llegado a vislumbrar, franceses y alemanes también) y me preguntaba si quizá alguien conocía de algún análisis o estudio respecto al mismo.
Me refiero a aquella sintaxis particular que los textos matemáticos exhiben y que uno como practicante de matemáticas termina por adoptar donde, a modo de ejemplo, se prefieren formas del estilo "Sea R una relación binaria sobre A, B dos subconjuntos de C una clase" por sobre una construcción más ordinaria como "Sea una relación binaria R sobre dos subconjuntos A y B de una clase C".
Otros dos ejemplos propios extraídos de un trabajo sobre técnicas de forzado:

"Pero entonces, dada g : ω ⥲ {f^n(a) : n ∈ ω}, notamos que g(2ω) ⊆ A la imagen según g de cada natural par conforma un conjunto de átomos infinito..."
"Tenemos S(A) el grupo de permutaciones de A y buscamos Φ(σ, x, y) una funcional una extensión de (σ, x) ↦ x una acción del grupo S(A) sobre  el universo t.q...."


El lenguaje matemático busca ser claro y eliminar cualquier tipo de ambigüedad, de ahí podría inferirse que se prefieran ciertos órdenes de palabras por sobre otros. Ahora, todos tus ejemplos parecen casos particulares de construcciones que están mal hechas. Lo siento pero no conozco ningún estudio que demuestre que es algo que sea generalizado aunque conozco a varios matemáticos, y sobre todo físicos e ingenieros a los que les falta más creatividad y expresividad en su estilo de redacción.

It you think this is a general form across languages you might be better seeing if it would fit on either the Linguistics site or the Mathematics site? I agree that I have never noticed any difference in constructions in my limited reading of texts not in English.

En Internet se pueden encontrar muchos sitios y documentos con información al respecto. Basta con buscar, por ejemplo: sintaxis textos matemáticos

Creo que el lenguaje matemático busca aclarar la diferencia entre lo que se construye y las características que ha de tener lo construido.  La construción que mencionas "sea R ..." nombra primero lo que se propone construir y luego especifica las características requeridas.
Si se cambia el órden de palabras, esa diferencia es menos visible.

Me parece que "sea ..." tiene significado condicional.

@Gustavson no es un condicional en absoluto

Condición en el sentido de premisa: let R be...

Se necesita una explicación sencilla, en lenguaje claro, para facilitar la comprensión de todos.
Se trata del lenguaje matemático, que es esencialmente universal.
Este lenguaje no utiliza palabras, sino símbolos.
Los símbolos utilizados son los mismos en todo el mundo.
Por ejemplo, la ecuación de Einstein E=mc² se entiende de la misma manera en cualquier idioma.
Cada símbolo tiene un significado concreto y preciso,
de modo que no puede entenderse de otro modo.
Estos símbolos son como las letras del alfabeto matemático,
salvo que no representan sonidos,
sino conceptos, operaciones, variables o relaciones fijas.
Por ejemplo, el símbolo ∏ corresponde a un número específico: 3,1416.
Las ecuaciones son como las oraciones del lenguaje matemático,
pero en lugar de sujetos y acciones, utilizan relaciones de igualdad,
indicadas por el símbolo = (igual).
Un ejemplo bien conocido es el teorema de Pitágoras: a² + b² = c².
Algunos cálculos matemáticos también pueden representarse con gráficos.
Los gráficos ayudan a reconocer mejor patrones o tendencias.
Un ejemplo sencillo es la curva o campana de Gauss.
La matemática es la ciencia madre.
Prácticamente la totalidad de las otras ciencias se sirven de ella, en mayor o menor medida.
Su “vocabulario” se construyó a lo largo de miles de años.
Útil para la ciencia porque se descarta cualquier interpretación errónea.
Entonces, “Sea R una relación binaria sobre A, B dos subconjuntos de C una clase”, en lenguaje matemático,   esto se escribiría de la siguiente manera:
R⊆A×A,B⊆C,C={x∣P(x)}
